# Need help binding json data to a controller action method - i'm stumped

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am missing something and I need some help.  I am at my wits end.  Everything looks correct, but I'm getting all null values for the model in the controller action method.

Any input would be appreciated.  Thanks!

I have the following action method on my controller...

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult RunReport(ReportSubmitModel  model)            
    {

    }
```

I have the following model class...

```
   public class ReportSubmitModel
   {
    public string[] RequiredParameters { get; set; }

    public string[] Companies { get; set; }

    public string[] AssetTypes { get; set; }

    public string[] ExpenseStatuses { get; set; }

    public string StartDate { get; set; }

    public string EndDate { get; set; }

    public string ReportGuid { get; set; }
   }
```

Here is what my Json looks like by calling JSON.stringify() and outptting it to the console.

```
[{"ReportGuid":"1011e87e-074b-4a40-bea6-ed271ab1e7ca"},{"Companies":["434b5d92-c41e-40b7-8490-11ed0047b232","966b8291-ff4c-4254-a475-cdc1277d014d","775ce236-a17f-41f0-b254-415163217181","129de43b-6fb1-475e-a6d2-28143750c973","fec4475a-e992-4560-b9b1-efd486ad10ca"]},{"AssetTypes":["192a3095-b33f-474f-af02-557ad5cb69f6","192a3095-b33f-474f-af02-557ad5cb69f6","34e3b858-a682-4936-8e43-c663a4df2cd2"]},{"RequiredParameters":["C","AT","FS","CS","SCH"]},{"StartDate":"1/1/2012"},{"EndDate":"1/1/2013"},{"ExpenseStatuses":["1","2"]}]
```

Here is what my ajax call looks like...

```
.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(postInfo),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "/Home/RunReport",
            success: loadReport});
```

UPDATE:  postInfo is an array that I am pushing values onto.

For example,  postInfo.push({ReportGuid: "guidvalue"});

Comment: please add how you populate `postInfo`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of all those extra curly brackets. I don't know how you built the javascript object but it should not be with `{`. With those in place, each item are treated as object and so you are in effect passing a collection object to your controller method. When your object is stringified it should look something like this:

```
{"ReportGuid": "1011e87e-074b-4a40-bea6-ed271ab1e7ca" ,
"Companies":["434b5d92-c41e-40b7-8490-11ed0047b232",
    "966b8291-ff4c-4254-a475-cdc1277d014d",
    "775ce236-a17f-41f0-b254-415163217181"]
```

Notice I removed the `{` before and after the `Companies` field. Actually you can build it like that in js, like this (I removed the other parts to simplify the example):

```
var postInfo = 
   {"ReportGuid": "1011e87e-074b-4a40-bea6-ed271ab1e7ca" ,
    "Companies":["434b5d92-c41e-40b7-8490-11ed0047b232",
        "966b8291-ff4c-4254-a475-cdc1277d014d"]};
```

Comment: I updated how I am populating the postInfo. postInfo as an array and i'm pushing values onto the array.

Comment: Like I mentioned, that's exactly your problem. Your method expects a single instance of `ReportSubmitModel` and yet you are passing a collection. Also, you are passing the `properties` as a collection which is not correct based on your model.

Comment: Ok, thanks von v.  I am working on making it a string right now.  Thanks again for your help :-)

Comment: You're welcome. I just wonder why you need to make it a string? I post an example how you can build the object in `js`. I understand you have arrays and `Companies` is an example of it. But you can still build the object not as a string. And stringify it later on using `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Ok, I know get your last comment.  I thought you were building it as a string when I looked it.  Looking at it again I see you are building Json.  :-).   It is late for me.   Thanks again!